# How do I buy an open jaw ticket for this itinerary?

Tags: air-travel, airlines, bookings

If I search for AMS-BUD 12/20/16 BUD-CDG 1/6/17 then KLM/Air France offers do not even appear.

If I search for AMS-BUD 12/20/16, return on 1/6/17 then the cheapest offer is on KLM on the way out and returning with Air France via CDG... (AF1295, AF1240).

It's not that the hidden city ticketing option is simply cheaper, it's that it *exists* while the other doesn't. What am I doing wrong when searching? I tried multiple OTAs and KLM itself. Should I call KLM? Do some weird trick on ITA Matrix I never heard of? Or just make sure I don't have checked in luggage in the middle of the winter and go hidden city ticketing??

[image]
[image]

Comment: It is possible that the fare classes that would be used to build your open jaw routing (AMS-BUD, BUD-CDG) are simply not available on those days.  Not every fare class can be recombined to make an open jaw.  I would call, as humans can sometimes build routes that computer algorithms overlook.

Comment: I checked a few more days because I am flexible on dates, somewhat. I will try the phone.

Comment: @chx does the BUD-CDG ticket appear if you search for it as a one-way?

Comment: Yes, but very expensive. If this fails I will take the train to BRU, fly Brussels Airlines (because they apparently charge point-to-point) and get an Easyjet Flexi ticket for the BUD-CDG leg (when they come up for sale in the summer). This is the best I can come up with starting from [The Hague](http://tedneeley.com/tour_dates/). Transavia a) flies too early b) does not let me carry two pieces of hand luggage on board. I have two pieces of hand luggage, end.

Comment: Are you married to KLM (or SkyTeam)? ITA shows flights from €166 for AMS-BUD 12/20/16 BUD-CDG 1/6/17 on Swissair, Lufthansa, etc.

Comment: @MichaelHampton chx may simply wish to fly directly

Comment: @Calchas I always want to fly directly, but there's a limit to how much I'm willing to spend to do it!

Comment: I am more married to travel time (and cost) than flying direct. Flying Lufthansa via Munich is a possibility but the time spent on the AMS-MUC-BUD-MUC-CDG flights are very likely to be no less than train-BRU-BUD (SN) ; BUD-CDG (U2) since the Hague - BRU train is only <1:30 longer than Hague-AMS...

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The reason is that there is no valid combination of fares that exist that can cover your desired route. Therefore there is no price for this itinerary. It is not for sale.

Inspection of the KL fare tariff on AMS-BUD reveals the reason. Even the most expensive full flex business class fare has the following restriction:

```
COMBINATIONS        
    END-ON-END NOT PERMITTED. SIDE TRIPS PERMITTED WITH
    NO RESTRICTIONS.
   OPEN JAWS/ROUND TRIPS/CIRCLE TRIPS
     FARES MAY BE COMBINED ON A HALF ROUND TRIP BASIS
     -TO FORM SINGLE OR DOUBLE OPEN JAWS WHICH CONSISTS
      OF NO MORE THAN 2 INTERNATIONAL FARE COMPONENTS AND
      THE OPEN SEGMENT AT ORIGIN MUST BE IN ONE COUNTRY.
      THE OPEN SEGMENT AT DESTINATION HAS NO RESTRICTIONS
 (snipped)
```

As you propose the open segment be at the origin and across two countries, KL has prevented the construction of this open jaw ticket with any of its fares.

If you force this via ITA, it will find a way to construct the ticket quote by using all-airline "YY" fares. IATA, the International Air Transport Association, creates these fares for historical reasons, and at one point they were accepted for travel by all IATA-member airlines. However, KLM will no longer accept tickets composed of YY fares, so the price it states is not valid.

[image: Price quote]

The commercial reason for this shortcoming is a mystery to me. Personally, I have very little faith in the revenue management group at the AF/KLM group and it may simply be a case of incompetence.

Of course, you can still buy your trip by purchasing two separate one-way tickets. Why AF/KLM have decided that this cannot be combined into an open jaw ticket at the same price is, as I say, not a question I can answer.

Comment: Wow. I presumed AF/KLM (as you mentioned, they are one group) will not care which hub I am ending with at the end of the open jaw (I reasoned the chances of using the group onwards is high) but apparently I am wrong. OK, alternative arrangements then.

Comment: @chx It makes no sense to me either.

Comment: If KLM reads this: I flew easyJet AMS-VIE and then easyJet BUD-CDG. I wanted to fly you but...