# Negotiating prices with airlines?

Tags: air-travel, budget, airlines, flight-search-engines, travel-agents

I'm traveling Toronto -> Chicago -> Tokyo -> Havana -> Toronto, all immediately after each other.

Skyscanner and Google Flights both (surprisingly) say that it's CHEAPER to do three separate 2-way flights:

- Toronto <-> Chicago
- Toronto <-> Tokyo
- Toronto <->  Havana

I would be willing to pay a bit more for 4 one-way tickets than the 3 two-way tickets, and this would also be better for the airline (Air Canada or United) since they would have to give me 4 boarding passes rather than 6 (!!). However, where would I even begin if I wanted to negotiate such a deal?

Comment: Have you been pricing this as four one-way tickets, or a single multi-city itinerary?

Comment: Unfortunately you don't have an avenue to negotiate individual tickets with mass commercial flights. Imagine the airlines would need to have an entire division of negotiators if they opened things that way. There's a benekfit to them for standardization. I use my airline miles for exactly this kind of scenario.

Comment: Try a different set of round trips, like Toronto-Chicago, Chicago-Tokyo, Chicago-Havana.  It might save time compare to the three you suggested, and you can arrange the timing so you don't need to leave O'Hare between the "connecting" flights.

Comment: @NateEldredge: I tried both of course. The multi-city searches don't always optimize very well, and choosing the cheapest 4 one-way tickets was cheaper than anything I found with a multi-city search, but still more expensive than doing 3 two-way flights!

Comment: @JohnZwinck: I of course tried that too (thank you Google Flights for the multiple airports function, and Kiwi for the radius search function which is a great idea but has never given me lower prices than other search engines). The problem is that the cheapest Chicago -> Tokyo/Osaka return flight is somehow $400 more than from Toronto, perhaps because these are with Air Canada and the Canadian dollar is ridiculously low right now. That $400 is almost the price of the two-way from Toronto to Havana!

Comment: You are mistaken if you believe that it'd be better for the airline. See this fantastic answer https://travel.stackexchange.com/a/49417/4188 on How do airlines determine ticket prices?Also see the insanity 
I hit in https://travel.stackexchange.com/a/66868/4188 where Budapest-Amsterdam/Paris-Budapest can be priced as a return but Amsterdam-Budapest/Budapest-Paris can't!

Comment: Have you tried a real travel agent, sometimes they will have "cheaper" fares.

Answer (score 11):

> However, where would I even begin if I wanted to negotiate such a deal?

Nowhere. There is no such thing as 'negotiating' with an airline, unless you're:

1. Getting bumped off an overbooked flight
2. Booking tickets for 50+ people at once
3. Working for a corporate sales office that handles tickets for a big organization

So forget it and go for hidden city ticketing or any other viable option on your route.

Comment: -1. You have made an assumption that the answer is "nowhere". Yet, you suggest there's a way to do it if I were to book 50+ tickets at once? How would I go about doing that? I don't appreciate being told to "forget it".

Comment: If you need 50 seats, ask a separate question please. As is the answer is nowhere.

Comment: You cannot possibly be 100% sure that the answer is "nowhere". Someone might have an idea regarding how to do it. However, with your answer sitting there with up votes, I worry that others will think the question's answered.